# Is there a translation for 'Piloncillo'?

Tags: traducción, comida

The dictionary says `brown sugar` but `azúcar moreno` is brown sugar. Besides `piloncillo` is solid and not a powder. I'm having a hard time explaining to Americans what `piloncillo` is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a translation into English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct spelling is `Piloncillo` and in some countries (Colombia, for example) it's also called `Panela`.

It could be translated to English as `brown sugar loaf` or just `brown sugar`

You can read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panela) for more information but here's an excerpt:

> Panela (Spanish pronunciation: [paˈnela]) is unrefined whole cane
>   sugar, typical of Latin America, which is basically a solid piece of
>   sucrose and fructose obtained from the boiling and evaporation of
>   sugarcane juice.

Comment: In Mexico, `Panela` is used to describe a type of cheese.

Comment: I don't what to be rude but as I stated is there another word besides brown sugar.

Comment: @Fortunato: I did quite some research online and `brown sugar loaf` was the only alternative I found besides `brown sugar`. This is not surprising since not every language has a 1:1 word for word translation. A `piloncillo` is just a solid mass of brown sugar. I think this is a good enough description to get the idea across. Regards!

Comment: @Flimzy: Queso panela is similar to queso cuajada in Colombia. I've been to Mexico several times and I loooooved queso panela ;)

Comment: I love Queso panela, too... especially grilled. :)